# Error handling for query string parameters -1%27, getting bombarded

Tags: asp.net

I am not an expert, but not a rookie either. I'm using Asp.net webforms. I set up an error catching routine in global.asax to log the error info in an SQL table and redirect to a friendly error page. I began finding hundreds of exceptions per day with this in the query string "?id=-1%27". I use query strings for items and categories but only allow integers of 3 digits or less. Then I started geo-locating the IPs. The vast majority of them are from Russia and surrounding countries. So I started storing all of the IPs in a table. Is anyone else experiencing this and how best to handle it. I want to catch legitimate errors, but this is a major annoyance. Any input would be appreciated. I have Googled for 2 days and can't find anything related specifically to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `%27` is ASCII for the single quote (`'`) and that is a red flag for someone trying to perform SQL injection via the query string to your application's data access layer logic.

I would be less concerned about where the attacks are coming from and more focused on techniques for protecting/processing your data before it is even attempted to be used by your data access layer and data storage (read: database).

Using parameterized SQL and data sanitation (read: white-listing allowable text for strings) is a great first step in combating these attacks.

*UPDATE*

It might be worth considering creating a custom exception for the invalid ID value being passed in as part of the query string. You can then test for the length being greater than three and throw that custom exception. Elsewhere you can catch/trap that custom exception type and do whatever you wish with that (read: potentially ignore that exception if it is becoming too large of annoyance). Please understand that I would never advocate ignoring exceptions (empty `catch` block), but merely stating that is possible to do such a "bad" thing.

Comment: I only use parametrized queries so that should good right? Plus as I said I only accept integer query strings.

Comment: Should I then code to ignore all "Conversion string to integer" exceptions?

Comment: @Steve - yes, you are fine in that respect. See UPDATE in answer for a potential solution to avoid your annoyance with these attack attempts.

Comment: I am considering blocking any IP that sends a malicious request in global.asax with Application_BeginRequest and sending them to a blank page before the session starts. Is that going overboard?

Comment: @Steve - it is just going to be a never-ending task of checking the exception logs and adding new IP addresses to your blocking logic. It is not overboard if you think it is beneficial.

Comment: Thanks for your input, very helpful. What I am doing now is capturing the IP of a thrown exception in a table. So, I don't have to check the logs. If I code to put into a BlockedIP table those IPs that send the -1%27 and then run that compare in the Application_BeginRequest can't I then send them away without any attention? There should be no effect on load since it only occurs when an exception occurs.